# How to translate webpack dev server proxy options to nginx docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx

I am deploying a docker container, which includes my webapp (app 1) to a vm. I have another docker container (app 2) on the vm that is running on `port 8080`. I would like to proxy all url requests from `app 1` that start with `/api` to `app 2`.

This is my DOCKER file:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.0
MAINTAINER **** [**@**.com](mailto:**@**.com)

COPY nginx.default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

ADD dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

These are my webpack dev server settings

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: outDir,
    // serve index.html for all 404 (required for push-state)
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://aapp-name:8080',
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
        logLevel: 'debug'
      }
    }
  }
```

I have added the following to `nginx.default`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://app-name:8080;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access container by name, you should place them in the same docker network.

- create docker network: `docker network create <network_name>`
- `docker run --network <network_name> --name app2 -d -p 8080:8080 image`
- `docker run --network <network_name> --name app1 -d image`
- access app2 service in app1 container by `http://app2:8080`